# Loop through list element and add text to the input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have along list li in div left  with text, and div right with form inputs I want to append the form list text to input value of div right,

Both divs have the same number of element;

This is what I have

```
$(".left li").each(function(){
  $(".right input").val($(".right input").val()+"_"+(this).text());
}); 

<div class="left">
<ul>
  <li> value from list1 <li> 
  <li> value from list2 <li>
  <li> value from list3 <li> 
</ul> 

</div> 

<div class="right">
<ul>
 <li> <input type="radio" name="somename" value="yes"> <li> 
 <li> <input type="radio" name="somename" value="yes"> <li> 
 <li> <input type="radio" name="somename" value="yes"> <li> 
</ul> 

</div>
```

I want the to archieve this

```
    <input type="radio" name="somename" value="yes_value from list1">
    <input type="radio" name="somename" value="yes_value from list2">
    <input type="radio" name="somename" value="yes_value from list3">
```

Comment: Format your code snippet as code and explain clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: What is you html structure? All you show is an input. Are the inputs contained in the li's or what? You need to provide more details.

Comment: change your $("input").val($("input").val()+"_"+(this).text()); to $("input").val($("input[name=somename]").val()+"_"+(this).text());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it

**UPDATE, TRY THIS:**

http://jsfiddle.net/p3e2fng1/

```
$("div.left li").each(function(e){

    var theid = e + 1;
    var theinput = $("div.right li:nth-of-type("+theid+")").find("input");

    theinput.val(theinput.val() + "_" + $(this).text());

});
```

Comment: Your code  could work if they are both on the li but ie input and li text , I have given more details on what i want to archive thanks